# How to share a password but hide the characters

Tags: text, encryption, passwords, hide, share

I have the need to share and send passwords to unlock documents and user levels in programs.I would like to be able to send a password that has the txt blocked or hidden with say an ### or *** I would like the receiver to be able to copy and paste it in the password field without them ever seeing the actual password. Is there a tool that can generate such a password? Is there a better way to do what I need done?

thank you

Gary

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

The `#` or `*` characters are simply substitutions that are performed by the (graphical) user interface of an application. In transit or in the clipboard the characters themselves are present as normal text. They are not different from any other text that is being copied.

What you could do is to let each participant generate PGP key pairs and distribute the public keys (as securely as possible). Then encrypt a text file containing the password using the public keys. Then the participants can decrypt the file/password and paste them into the field.